# Why a new column appears when resetting the index of a pandas df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This was the DataFrame, I was trying to reset the index -

[This is what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Sma.png)
and I am unable to understand the reason for `level_0` being displayed here as a column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your index's series name is level_0, when you do the `reset_index()`, it comes as a new column. You can drop it in the same way with `.reset_index(drop=True)`.

`df.reset_index(drop=True).drop('index',axis=1)` will give you the output without level_0.

Comment: if you do ```df.reset_index(drop=True)``` it will drop that index column. The ```drop('index',axis=1)``` appears to be redundant and in my case it caused an error. I think is either or but not both.